# How to set up JAVA_OPTS for AspectJ to work in Tomcat running as a service on a Windows Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, tomcat7, aspectj, catalina, java-opts

**Problem**

I need to integrate AspectJ code into an existing application running on Tomcat, but I think I am not setting JAVA_OPTS correctly.

Our vendor has created some AspectJ code that passes logged in user id information to the CONTEXT_INFO() object within MSSQLServer Connection. This is so that within an audit database trigger that we created, we can capture the user id that made the change.

**What I have done**

1. Added the following code to our database trigger

   DECLARE @appUserID INT

   SET @appUserID = ISNULL(REPLACE(CONVERT(VarChar(128), CONTEXT_INFO()),CHAR(0), ''), '0');
2. Added **aspectjrt.jar** to the web application WEB-INF\lib folder.
3. Added **vendorAspectJCode.jar** to the web application WEB-INF\lib folder.
4. Added **aspectjweaver.jar** to tomcat's lib folder **\tomcat7.0.27\lib**
5. Edited **catalina.bat** with the following:

there is a line of code that looks like this:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%
```

I have changed that to

```
 set JAVA_OPTS=”%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG% -javaagent:D:\tomcat\tomcat7.0.27\lib\aspectjweaver.jar"
```

but it did not seem to work.

So then I have tried setting it like that, adding a new set JAVA_OPTS:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%
set JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:D:\tomcat\tomcat7.0.27\lib\aspectjweaver.jar"
```

but that did not seem to do the trick either

After making the following changes and running a test through the web application front end, the user id that was inserted into the database was **0**, so that tells me that something has not been done right and the part that I feel less comfortable with all of the steps above was Step 5.

1. Does anybody know if the syntax for setting JAVA_OPTS is correct?
2. or whether there is another place to put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I found out how to integrate AspectJ in Tomcat **running as a Service on a Windows server**. I do not know why, but the bolded stuff was the cause to my problems.

Of course, as I mentioned in my question above you need the following prerequisites:

1. Add **aspectjrt.jar** to the web application WEB-INF\lib folder.
2. Add **vendorAspectJCode.jar** to the web application WEB-INF\lib folder.
3. Add **aspectjweaver.jar** to tomcat's lib folder \tomcat7.0.27\lib

Setting **-javaagent:PathToMyAspectjweaver\aspectjweaver.jar** in the **service.bat** did not work. So I had to set it in the registry along with **uninstalling/installing** the Tomcat service for changes to be picked up by doing as follows:

1. First I recommend turning **UAC** off and to make sure that you are an **Administrator**
2. **Stop** the Tomcat service if running.
3. **Delete** the tomcat service.
4. **Verify** in Windows Services that the service is no longer there.
5. **Verify** the Windows registry that everything related to the service got deleted. If not, do so manually.
6. **Install** the Tomcat service.
7. **Verify** in Windows Services that the service got created.
8. Find the service in the registry and edit the variable **Options** apppending the following:

   -javaagent:PathToMyAspectjweaver\aspectjweaver.jar

I have created a couple of bat files for these steps. Steps 2 and 3 would look something similar to this below (**TomcatServiceUninstall.bat**):

```
echo OFF
ECHO Removing Tomcat Service...
sc stop YourServiceName
sc delete YourServiceName
ECHO Removing Registry Key containing config data for Tomcat7
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\YourServiceName" /f
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat\7.0" /f
ECHO Uninstall Complete - File Directories remain intact.
```

Step 6 would look like that (**TomcatServiceInstall.bat**)

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO Running Service.bat to install the Tomcat 7 - YourServiceName - Service
cd "C:\Path to your tomcat\tomcat7.0.27\bin"
service.bat install
```